# Is it possible to assign different colours to certain XML tags in VS Code?

Tags: xml, visual-studio-code, color-scheme

I have a rather long XML document, and I'd love for certain tags to be displayed in a certain color (for example every  tag should be red) Is there an add-on or a way to do that in Visual Studio Code?

Comment: use the extension HighLight https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fabiospampinato.vscode-highlight

Answer (score 0):

Use the [scopes inspector](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide#scope-inspector) from the command palette, you will see that xml tags have the following scope:

```
entity.name.tag.localname.xml
meta.tag.xml
text.xml
```

So that putting this into your settings will change your tag color:

```
 "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {

    "textMateRules": [

      {
        "scope": "entity.name.tag.localname.xml",
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#f00",
          // "fontStyle": "underline"
        }
      }
  }
```

Comment: So, that's how I can change the color of every tag, right? I only want to change, for example, <room> tags but for other ones to stay the same color they were. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: @itsMikan I hope your question will get a proper answer. However, I find your question a bit vague. Specifically, you should ask how to display only the `<room>` tag in green, for example, and all other tags in red.